# virtual hosts problem in apache 2.2

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, centos

i have strange problem in virtual host configurations,
this is what is currentky have:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80

   <VirtualHost  *:80>  
 ServerAdmin webmaster@site1.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1.com
 ServerName site1.co.il 
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost  *:80>  
 ServerAdmin webmaster@site2.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2.com
 ServerName site2.com 
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost  *:80>  
 ServerAdmin webmaster@site3.com    
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site3.com
 ServerName site3.com
 </VirtualHost>
```

if i'm changing the order, everything goes wrong!
i dont unterstand why the order is important!
if i am adding a new site, and refering new domain to my ip,
if i wont put it first, it will reffer to other domain..

(runs os centos, apache vertion: 2.2)
does someone knows what can i do?
thanks alot!

Comment: if you solved it you can answer your own question and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am following what the problem is.  All three domains look like they will bind to the same IP address so if you access your sites using the apache server IP address the first DocumentRoot will be served.

If you don't have domains pointed to these websites you could set your hosts file to the ServerName or any alias defined in each  section to access those specific DocumentRoots.

Comment: and how i do that in the hosts file?

Comment: sorry guys, the problem been solved,
the problem was that i didnt added
serverAlias